# redirecting to home page in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

i have a problem which is when i refresh the page it goes back me to home page,that because  when i check a user if is logged in using Firebase it redirect automatically to home page.
some can someone help me to fix this problem,thank you in advance.
App.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import Navbarr from './Component/Navbarr/Navbarr';
import Home from './Component/Home/Home';
import About from './Component/About/About';
import Contact from './Component/Contact/Contact';
import Javascript from './Component/Javascript/Javascript';
import Php from './Component/Php/Php';
import Profile from './Component/Profile/Profile';
import Python from './Component/Python/Python';
import Askquestion from './Component/Askquestion/Askquestion';
import Articles from './Component/Articles/Articles';
import Login from './Component/Login/Login';
import Register from './Component/Register/Register';
import './App.css';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {BrowserRouter as Router,Switch,Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import SidePanel from './Component/SidePanel/SidePanel';


class App extends React.Component{

constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
    }
}

render()
{
return(
<Router>
<Navbarr  />
<SidePanel currentUser={this.props.currentUser}/>
<Switch>
<Route path='/' exact component={Home}/>
<Route path='/Askquestion'  component={Askquestion}/>
<Route path='/Javascript'  component={Javascript}/>
<Route path='/Php' component={Php}/>
<Route path='/Python' component={Python}/>
<Route path='/About' component={About}/>
<Route path='/Contact' component={Contact}/>
<Route path='/Profile' component={Profile}/>
<Route path='/Articles' component={Articles}/>
<Route path='/Login' component={Login}/>
<Route path='/Register' component={Register}/>
</Switch>
</Router>

  );


}

}

const mapstatetoprops=state=>({
    currentUser:state.user.currentUser
})
export default connect(mapstatetoprops) (App) ;
```

Index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import {Provider,connect} from 'react-redux';
import {createStore} from 'redux';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import {BrowserRouter as Router,Switch,Route,withRouter} from 'react-router-dom';
import {composeWithDevTools} from 'redux-devtools-extension';
import rootReducer from './Reducers/Reducers';
import Login from './Component/Login/Login';
import Register from './Component/Register/Register';
import{setuser,clearUser} from './Actions/Actions';
import firebase from './Component/firebase/firebase';
import Spinner from './Component/Spinner/Spinner';

const store=createStore(rootReducer,composeWithDevTools());
     class Root extends React.Component{
    componentDidMount(){
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user=>{
        if(user){
      const currentroute=this.props.history.location.pathname;

        this.props.setuser(user);
      this.props.history.push('/');
        }else{
        this.props.history.push('/Login')
        this.props.clearUser();
      }
    })

    }

    render(){

    return this.props.isLoading ? <Spinner/>:  (
  <Switch>

  <Route exact path='/'  component={App}/>
  <Route path='/Register' component={Register}/>
  <Route path='/Login' component={Login}/>

   </Switch>



    )

    }


}
const mapStateFromProps=state=>({

    isLoading:state.user.isLoading

})
const RootWithAuth=withRouter(connect(mapStateFromProps,{setuser,clearUser})(Root));
ReactDOM.render(
   <Provider store={store}>
   <Router> 

    <RootWithAuth />

  </Router>

  </Provider>
  ,document.getElementById('root')
);

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

and guys just want to know i can provide the project on git hub if you want .

Comment: what page are you on when it redirects you back?

Comment: hi @RedBaron  ,whatever page ,let's say i'am in the page called  contact  once i refresh it redirect me to home

Comment: have you tried adding `exact` for each route like this: `<Route path='/Articles'  exact component={Articles}/>`

Comment: @RedBaron i remove exact from Route in root component and it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After checking whether the user is logged in you can redirect to the currentpath rather than redirecting to home page

```
  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
  if (user) {
    const currentroute = this.props.location.pathname;
    this.props.setuser(user);
    this.props.history.push(currentroute);
  } else {
    this.props.history.push('/Login')
    this.props.clearUser();
  }
})
```

Comment: Hi @Harikrishnan ,thanks for the answer ,when i do that  it stay in the same route but it display nothing on the page it's empty .

Comment: could you please add the project to something like codesanbox

Comment: @Salah Please do remove the exact from `Route` in `Root ` component

Comment: it works friend thank you a lot now i released the mistake